# Using an escape character with a beginning wildcard in regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Below is a sample of an email I am using from a database:

```
2.2|[johnnyappleseed@example.com]
```

Every line is different, and it may or may not be an email, but it will always. I am trying to use regular expressions to get the information inside the brackets. Below is what I have been trying to use:

```
^\[\]$
```

Unfortunately, every time I try to use it, the expression isn't matching. I think the problem is using the escape characters, but I am not sure. If this is not how I use the escape characters with this, or if I am wrong completely, please let me know what the actual regex should be.

Comment: That expression matches the start of the line immediately followed by a `[`, immediately followed by a `]` immediately followed by the end of the line. Does that sound like it would match your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close to yours is `^.*\[(.*)\]$`:

- `^` start of the line
- `.*` anything
- `\[` a bracket, indicating the start of the email
- `(.*)` anything (the email), as a capturing group
- `\]` a square bracked, indicating the end of the email
- `$` end of the line

Note that your Regex is missing the `.*` parts to match the things between the key characters [ and ].

Answer (score 1):

Your regex - `^\[\]$` - matches a single string/line that only contains `[]`, and you need to obtain a substring inbetween the square brackets somewhere further inside a larger string.

You can use

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\[)[^]]+");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(s).Value);
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c%5b)%5b%5e%5d%5d%2b&i=2.2%7c%5bjohnnyappleseed%40example.com%5d)

With `(?<=\[)` we find the position after `[` and then we match every character that is not `]` with `[^]]+`.

Another, non-regex way:

```
var s = "2.2|[johnnyappleseed@example.com]";
var ss = s.Split('|');
if (ss.GetLength(0) > 1)
{
    var last = ss[ss.GetLength(0)-1];
    if (last.Contains("[") && last.Contains("@")) // We assume there is an email
        Console.WriteLine(last.Trim(new[] {'[', ']'}));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo of both approaches](http://ideone.com/tfcABK)